# Is there a way to estimate regression coefficients?

Tags: regression, data-imputation, multiple-imputation

I'm currently working on a simulation study (based on empirical data) and for this simulation I created a model with multiple interaction terms. The interaction terms are between categorical variables, which results in a lot of regression coefficients to be estimated. The problem is that some interactions have no data, which results in NA for these combinations. Is there a way to impute these coefficients?

More info about the empirical dataset:
It is a dataset with recruitment campaigns. It has 5 variables that are of main interest: 1) Function (26 levels), 2) Education (5 levels), 3) Region (12 levels), 4) Duration of campaign in days, 5) Job boards used (300+ levels).

I include interaction terms between function and education, function and region, and between education and region.

Comment: How many observations do you have? This is a lot of parameters ... Maybe look into lasso, or the fused lasso (search this site)

Comment: I have 2778 observations. Of the 461 interaction terms, 108 return NA. Lasso could be a good alternative, I did not think of that before!

Comment: Did you look at cross-tables (i.e., contingency tables) of function and education, function and region and education and region in your empirical dataset? Are all the cells of those tables non-zero?

Comment: All of these cells are zero (missing).